# Where to set "define()" within ZendFramework to ensure persistence

Tags: php, security, zend-framework, php-5.3

I am currently working on some authentification and cryptography stuff.
I thought about implementing my APP_SECRET (aka Salt) globally with define.

The problem is I do not want to put the APP_SECRET in my index.php due to security reasons.
Which is the next but earliest executed file I should insert my APP_SECRET in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a better idea to set it in your config file. That is what it is meant for. See [Zend_Config](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.config.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can register a plugin in the bootstrap file which will only define constants.
If you have a ini file for application configuration values, you can put it there too.
Or, quick and dirty:

1. put it in the bootstrap file itself
2. include a constants file in the index.php (a file which will sit outside the public dir
3. do it in initializer.php